# How do I invite Liara to show me her new project?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I got an email from Liara asking me to invite her to my quarters when I have time to go over some new project she's working on.  The comm will only let me call Samantha Traynor, Diana Allers and James Vega; in that order.

How do I trigger the game to let me invite Liara?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize but she'd actually already showed me her Time Capsule project.  I just didn't realize the email was for that. I cleared out the inbox far later after I'd already see it.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Good to see this, but now I'm wondering if that was supposed to be the romance opportunity like the others were.  Did I just miss it?

Comment: No.  I don't think so.  If memory serves I had the Liara romance option much later.  You can visit her in the Citadel (the park area with tables) and pursue the option from there.

Answer (score 2):

Try letting one of the others in and then going back to the CIC before going back to your cabin to call her in. If that doesn't work, go to your Crew Quarters and talk to her in person, then try calling her in your cabin. Short of this, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: No dice. Going to CIC before each call doesn't so it. Neither does dropping by Liara's quarters. I Guess the new project is not that important.

Comment: @SMTF: It totally *is* that important!  That was one of the most touching scenes in the entire game, IMHO!  Liara's great that way. Sorry you're having trouble getting it to trigger...

Comment: @rbwhitaker: Ah, your talking about the Time Capsule.  I did see that. I must not have read the email till long after I'd seen it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Keep talking to her after every mission and she will eventually e-mail you.